# Android build error (Slim7.1) because of ALSA

Tags: android, build, alsa, android-7.1-nougat, ninja

Totally new to ROM building! Trying to build slim for the LG K20 Plus TP260 (MSM8917)

I've downloaded LG's source and have tried to assimilate it into Slim's source (basically merging everything but the frameworks folder) and am now trying to build.

But this is the Ninja error I get:

```
ninja: Entering directory `.'
ninja: error: '/home/android/Desktop/cheap_android_love/out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr', needed by '/home/android/Desktop/cheap_android_love/out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libtinyalsa_intermediates/mixer.o', missing and no known rule to make it
build/core/ninja.mk:151: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

I've checked the directory, and the "obj" folder doesn't even exist, so this error seems impossible to me... What files do I need to look at?

Comment: Interesting. I maintain a copy of tinyalsa on github but I haven't looked at Android's copy in a while. I can take a look but it won't be until later on today or tomorrow.

Comment: I think the ninja script might have been created by a CMake generator, so look for the CMakeLists.txt file that deals with tinyalsa.

Comment: [[[see answer]]]

Answer (score 0):

After changes to BoardConfig.mk and Kernel.mk makefiles regarding target kernel config and target source, everything goes together fine!